# azure instead of LA(MP)

Tags: azure

I'd be grateful for any "step by step" guides in what it takes to change the code on the dynamic data base connections/connection string/ etc on the PHP/HTML pages to have it working "plug n play" by ftp the pages and MySQL database to be hosted on "Azure Websites"

Thx a lot

Comment: I did not understand the question clearly. Do you want to know how to integrate MySql database (hosted on Azure) connection with PHP site (running as Azure website)? Would u please make it more clear?

Comment: This question is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Let me rephrase the question (based on my understanding of it), and follow up with my suggested solution.

**Current Scenario**:

- PHP/HTML website
- MySQL database
- connection string points to local db

**Planned Scenario**:

- Azure Website (aka Web App)
- FTP/deploy PHP site to Azure
- Migrate MySQL db to Azure

**Would like to have**:

- Database connection strings entered once
- Local DB should work when running locally
- Web/Cloud DB should work between repeated deployments

**Solution**

1. Create & Deploy PHP/MySQL Web App
2. Configure using environment variables (to detect local vs web/cloud)
3. Use staging slots for swapping staging/production

**Links**

1. Deploy: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-php-mysql-deploy-use-ftp/
2. Configure: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/
3. Staging Slots: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-staged-publishing/